# Keep the foreign key constraint using soft delete

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key, delete

I have a product table and it is foreign key for product ingredients table.

Is there a way to check if it is fk referenced before making `isdeleted = true` without manually querying for it?

Answer (score 1):

You could make `<primary key>` plus `<isdeleted>` a composite unique key, and reference that in the foreign keys instead of the primary key, though this would feel a bit dirty to me. You would need to have a column in the referring table to hold `ingredientisdeleted=0` and perhaps have a default & constraint on that to force it to remain 0.

You could use triggers to raise an error instead of allowing the update if there are referring keys, so you don't need to explicit code that everywhere that you might want to set `isdeleted`. This is still manual coding but only ever in one place, though you need to remember to update it if new FKs to this table are added (or you need to write it so it scans for FKs to verify, but this would be messy & inefficient). It would be less efficient than the extra unique index if the table sees a lot of updates, but would remove the requirement to store (and remember to reference instead of PK) the extra composite index.

A further option is to reconsider your model a little. Could you use [temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables) to track old data instead of traditional soft deletes? That way the normal PK/FK relationship will just work for your day-to-day data modifications, with the disadvantage that some queries⁰ needing to output deleted items become a little more complex.

<sub><sub>--

[0] though other queries become significantly easier, or even just practical at all where they were not before, with FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF and related syntactic sugar, so this could be a larger consideration for your app overall</sub></sub>

Answer (score 0):

You could require the `UPDATE` to reference a subquery that will return no results if references exist. Then, if 0 rows are updated, you can raise a message to the UI to report an error.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no - code must be written somewhere. A constraint (using a UDF) or a trigger could prevent this.

In my experience, soft-deletes are usually done to keep ALL of an object's attributes and related bits in the database.

Requiring the related bits to be physically removed seems to defeat the purpose - but no one knows your system and its design.

Answer (score 0):

Using soft deletes *invariably* leads to more complex SQL because you're having to allow for things that exists, but that you want to treat as if they didn't.

That said, it *is* only one extra element on each JOIN clause to check it ...

```
select . . . 
from ingredients i 
left join products p
   on i.product_id = p.id 
  and not( p.isdeleted ) 
. . .
```

A compound index (*not* PK) on `products` { `id`, `isdeleted` } would greatly help with this.